# Can the Vision survive without the gem in his forehead?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, avengers-age-of-ultron

In *The Avengers: Age of Ultron*, we saw the newly introduced character Vision, whose creation partly involved

> the Mind Stone Infinity Gem being fused to his forehead. His possession of the Gem is used to explain a number of important aspects of his behavior.

If that gem were removed, would Vision (as he exists at the end of the movie) continue to exist? Is that element required to allow his body to contain his consciousness in the first place?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's confirmed early in *Avengers: Infinity War* that the removal or destruction of

> the Mind Stone

would indeed result in Vision's death. **However**, we also learn that it's possible for Shuri to perform a complex, delicate procedure to re-map Vision's neurons, in such a way that he *can* survive without the gem.

> Unfortunately, the procedure isn't completed in time, and we get canon proof that the stone's removal would kill Vision when Wanda destroys it. Then we get further proof when Thanos rewinds time and rips the stone out of Vision's forehead. Vision is killed on both occasions.

Answer (score 9):

#### If we treat the Infinity Stones as if they are the reality-altering objects they appear to be both in the Marvel Cinematic Universe (Earth-199999) and in the Marvel-Canon Universe (Earth-616) there is no reason to expect the Vision's program won't remain in existence and continue to drive his android body for the foreseeable future.

- We are not sure how the Mind Stone works, the range of its powers, and how long any of its effects could last for the artificial mind/program that is the Vision's mind. We assume there is a computer housed within the body of the Vision and this is where his altered program resides.

[image]

*On the Marvel Earth, the Vision has been disassembled more than once...*

- While the gem's mind control capacities appear limited and temporary, this may have nothing to do with the Gem and have everything to do with the user's ability to utilize the powers of the Infinity Gem. So far, we have seen the powers of the Gem completely capable of changing aspects of reality, if the user is powerful and capable enough.

RUMOR and SPECULATION

- **[The Vision](http://marvel.wikia.com/Vision_(Earth-616)#Powers)** in the Marvel Canon Universe had a gem on his forehead called the solar jewel. It allowed the Vision to absorb ambient energy from the environment and use it as a power source. It also allows him to emit energy from the gem itself or his eyes if he desires. The gem also powered his energy core which allowed him to perform a variety of physical feats such as mass alteration, levitation and utilize superhuman strength.

[image]

**Rumor speculates the gem on the Vision's forehead in the MCU is:**

> **[The Soul Gem](http://marvel.wikia.com/Soul_Gem)**. While many fans expected it to be on the head of [Adam Warlock](http://marvel.wikia.com/Adam_Warlock_(Earth-616)) and we have been given a glimpse of his cocoon in the hands of the Collector, it is speculated he will not have a role in the MCU and since we have a need to introduce the Infinity Stones, the Vision would be the perfect receptacle for such a stone. It would explain how his program came to life and maintains his "living android" state. Of course this is all speculation and rumor, until it's disproved or replaced with MCU canon.

[image]

Comment: What issue is that from? I'm curious why Mockingbird would be showing Wanda her husband in such a state.

Comment: The Vision had attacked the Avengers after having his mind and body infiltrated by Ultron who had hidden within him using a control chip. He was completely disassembled to be sure there was nothing left of Ultron within him. He attacked the Avenger's during John Byrne's "Absolute Vision" run circa Avengers #254 (1985) or thereabout.

Comment: Ah, ok - I remember that happening, although I didn't see this part. That was, in fact, the incident referred to in "Avengers Disassembled" when they stated that Ultron had taken over The Vision AGAIN. In fact, the more you learn about Wanda, the more you can sympathize with her going nuts.

Comment: This answer probably needs to be updated, specifically re: the rumor about the gem in the MCU (we now know what it is)

Comment: Also: James Gunn went on the record to say [that wasn't Warlock's cocoon](http://moviepilot.com/posts/2014/12/05/guardians-of-the-galaxy-s-james-gunn-talks-adam-warlock-2485092?lt_source=external,manual).

Comment: @ThaddeusHowze - Byrne was writing and drawing *Fantastic Four* during the "Absolute Vision" storyline. The writer of that story was Roger Stern. Also, Ultron had nothing to do with that storyline; Vision decided to take over with some influence by Isaac, the computer that ran Titan. Eros (Thanos' brother, also known as Starfox) was a member of the team at that time, and offered Isaac's help when Vision was badly injured.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's safe to assume that the stone is not required for the Vision body to function.  Given that Ultron originated as an AI in

> the scepter's gem encasing the Mind Stone.

And Ultron is clearly familiar with the stone's capabilities, given his integrating it into the Vision's design.  However, since Ultron's plan was

> to inhabit the Vision's body himself,

it seems unlikely that he would make the body entirely dependent on the stone.  To do so would be an unnecessary weakness for

> his ultimate form.

Since Ultron has knowledge of the stone and its capabilities, it's likely he knows its history and importance.  That means he likely knows that people **cough** would probably steal it at some point in the future, which makes a dependence on it a bad idea.

Mind you, the stone is clearly the source of energy blasts, so Vision would lose that capability if he lost the stone.

Comment: I feel this makes sense... The gem was merely an accessory of sorts. The core of the Vision body was JARVIS.

Comment: Yes I think that without the mind gem he could still live, but would lose all his power. If it ever happens, I guess it wouldn't hurt the other avengers to patch up his forehead and give him hand to hand combat training; it's always nice to a have a soldier that is 1/3 vibranium.

Answer (score -1):

No, it's an integral part of his form and function.  Curious though as to why Ultron would develop an 'inferior' body of flesh versus adamantium.  Or maybe make an adamantium suit of armor for battle - similar to his 'father' Iron Man.

Comment: Can you cite a source for the claim that it's an integral part of his form and function?

Comment: His "father" doesn't have an adamantium suit.

Comment: I thought he was made of Vibranium?

Comment: its made of a mixture of artificially created organic tissue bonded on a molecular level  with vibranium using Cho's cradle

Comment: The MCU cannot legally refer to anything as Adamantium, since the copyright on that name is tied to the rights to Wolverine and the X-men, who are owned by fox, who have refused to lend the rights to marvel studios